# enabling thinkpad fn keys in openbox

Tags: debian, openbox, thinkpad

I recently abandoned `gnome` and switched to a minimal `openbox` setup without any desktop environment. However, of the function keys on my laptop (ThinkPad), only the brightness keys are now responsive (they all worked properly in my previous desktop environment -- gnome 3 fallback). How can I restore function to the other Fn keys (volume, display device, etc)?

Comment: Could you first run `xev` and test if it reacts when the keys are pressed?

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens: Yes, the keys do elicit a response in `xev`. What's odd is that there are no keybindings for any of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys in my `rc.xml` file (`openbox` config file), so what is handling the display brightness keys (and not the other special keys) is unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Gnome and other full desktop environments (DE) there is a standard binding for special keys like `XF86AudioLowerVolume`. These are preconfigure by the DE developers to execute code, since it makes sense to lower the volume with the Gnome Mixer when you press `XF86AudioLowerVolume`.

With Openbox there is no standard sound mixer, so you have to define the function of all your special keyboard keys yourself in the `rc.xml` file.

Here is an example for lowering the volume

```
<keybind key="XF86AudioLowerVolume">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>amixer sset Master,0 5-</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

The brightness keys are a different thing.
It is not always clear how they are handled.
On some laptops these keys are not handle by the OS but by the firmware, and  on my Dell Inspirion Mini 10 the the keys only work on Linux and not on FreeBSD, which makes me belief that there is a driver needed to handle the brightness keys on my Mini.

So what you have experienced is normal and you just need to find programs that can do the things you want when you press a special key and bind them to the key.
With the exception of the brightness keys, which sometimes work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try assigning bindings to all the keys. I find it interesting that some of the key bindings are firmware-dependent while others are software-dependent.

Comment: @user001 In a way it makes sense that you can adjust the brightness even if the OS is not fully operational. But the problem is that there is no standard way of handling such a common task.

Comment: +1 for precisely describing the keys on my Acer Aspire One AO722 - brightness in firmware, volume needed configured in `rc.xml`. Seems odd how Debian LXDE provisions a standard mixer/volume applet (via LxPanel) yet doesn't bind volume keys when available from X. I added OB bindings to `amixer set Master 10%+`, minus, and mute. Great!